# get resulting type of std::bind

Tags: c++, decltype, result-of

I'm trying to get the resulting type of std::bind in combination with a lambda. I've tried the following two:

```
template<typename F>
typename std::result_of<std::bind(F,uint)> func(F f, uint i);
```

This doesn't work for whatever reason. I've also tried using decltype:

```
template<typename F>
decltype(std::bind(F(),uint()) func(F f, uint i);
```

This doesn't work, because when i use this template function with a lambda f, then it complains that lambdas have a deleted default constructor.

Can you please help me out here? I've unsuccessfully tried finding answers on the net.

Thank you!

Comment: `template<typename F>
auto func(F f, uint i) -> decltype(std::bind(f, i));` or use `std::declval` for C++11. `decltype(auto)` for C++14.

Comment: bind in combination with lambda? There is no reason to use bind at all. Use lambda.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using `decltype(auto)` as follows:

```
template<typename F>
decltype(auto) func(F f, uint i) { // ... }
```

so the return type will be deduced by compiler.

---

Then, I don't think that [`std::result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) is an appropriate tool in this case.

But with [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype), you might also do exactly what @Jarod42 mentioned in the comment: use a *trailing return type*:

```
template<typename F>
auto func(F f, uint i) -> decltype(std::bind(f, i)) { // ... }
```

which should also work with *C++11* (the very first solution requires *C++14* support).